# Generate random sum equation when current answer is correct

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<body> 
 
<div class="container">
  <div class="center">
  <h1>Zeen Game</h1>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body"><input type="text" id="oneA"> + <input type="text" id="oneB"> answer:<input type="text" id="ansone"><input type="button" value="check" onclick="checkAns('one')"/></div>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("oneA").value=Math.floor(Math.random()*11+1);
    document.getElementById("oneB").value=Math.floor(Math.random()*11+1);

    function checkAns(grade){
        var answer = Number(document.getElementById(grade+"A").value) + 
                     Number(document.getElementById(grade+"B").value);
        if (answer==Number(document.getElementById("ans"+grade).value)) {
            alert("well done!");
        } else {
            alert("try again!");
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
```

I have function "check answer" for the sum of two random numbers.
I want that when the current answer is correct, then generate new random numbers for making a new sum equation.

Comment: [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/bmk476q7/)?

Answer (score 0):

You must add the two first line of your script into the `if` statement block and clear the answer block for next equation,
like this

```html
<body> 
 
<div class="container">
  <div class="center">
  <h1>Zeen Game</h1>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body"><input type="text" id="oneA"> + <input type="text" id="oneB"> answer:<input type="text" id="ansone"><input type="button" value="check" onclick="checkAns('one')"/></div>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("oneA").value=Math.floor(Math.random()*11+1);
    document.getElementById("oneB").value=Math.floor(Math.random()*11+1);

    function checkAns(grade){
        var answer = Number(document.getElementById(grade+"A").value) + 
                     Number(document.getElementById(grade+"B").value);
        if (answer==Number(document.getElementById("ans"+grade).value)) {
            alert("well done!");
            document.getElementById("ans"+grade).value = '';
            document.getElementById("oneA").value=Math.floor(Math.random()*11+1);
            document.getElementById("oneB").value=Math.floor(Math.random()*11+1);
        } else {
            alert("try again!");
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: you are welcome. please upvote and accept the answer